# Issue with passing arguments to a named callback function in angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I want to **factor out** the angularjs **$http success callback function** so that instead of having two (or N) **anonymous callback functions** I have **one named callback function**.

Here are the two controllers:

```
function CreateCurriculumCtrl($scope, $http, $location, select2Options){

    $scope.curriculumInfo = {};
    $scope.curriculumInfo.statusOK = true;
    $scope.select2Options = select2Options; 

    $scope.saveCurriculum = function(){
        $http.post('bignibou/curriculum/new', $scope.curriculumInfo).success(function(curriculumInfo) {
            if(curriculumInfo.statusOK == true){
                $scope.curriculumInfo.statusOK=true;
                $location.path('/view/'+curriculumInfo.curriculum.id);
            }
            else{
                $scope.curriculumInfo.statusOK = false;
                $scope.curriculumInfo.errors = curriculumInfo.errors;
            }           
        });
    };
}

function EditCurriculumCtrl($scope, $http, $location, select2Options, $routeParams){

    $scope.curriculumInfo = {};
    $scope.curriculumInfo.statusOK = true;
    $scope.select2Options = select2Options;
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

    $http.get('/bignibou/utils/findCurriculumById.json',{params: {id: $routeParams.id}}).success(
            function(curriculum){
                $scope.curriculumInfo.curriculum = curriculum;
            });

    $scope.editCurriculum = function(){
        $http.post('bignibou/curriculum/edit/'+$routeParams.id, $scope.curriculumInfo)
        .success(function(curriculumInfo) {
            if(curriculumInfo.statusOK == true){
                $scope.curriculumInfo.statusOK=true;
                $location.path('/view/'+curriculumInfo.curriculum.id);
            }
            else{
                $scope.curriculumInfo.statusOK = false;
                $scope.curriculumInfo.errors = curriculumInfo.errors;
            }           
        });
    };
}
```

I am not sure how to do that because **what will become the named callback function has a couple of dependencies (i.e. $scope and $location).**

If I extract the function (named callback) out of the angularjs controllers, then the named 
callback **has no longer access to its dependencies**.

***Can anyone please help with factoring out the success callback function and making sure the dependencies are satisfied?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass them as arguments.

First, `$http.post` expects the callback to accept one argument. So we write the function that `post` expects:

```
function (curriculumInfo) {
    // .....
}
```

But the body of the function needs access to `$scope` and `$location`. So we write a function that accepts those and return the function that `post` expects:

```
function (scope,location) {
    return function (curriculumInfo) {
        // ... use scope and location in here
    }
}
```

Now we can name the function appropriately. Lets see, it's handling the response to new curriculum so I'd call it either `new_curriculum_callback` or `new_curriculum_callback` or `handle_new_curriculum` to indicate that it's a callback:

```
function handle_new_curriculum (scope,location) {
    return function (curriculumInfo) {
    }
}
```

Now you can call it to return the callback function to `post`:

```
$http
    .post('bignibou/curriculum/new',$scope.curriculumInfo)
    .success(handle_new_curriculum($scope,$location));
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a Curriculum service and refactor every call to the backend into it.
Your controllers shouldn't care on how to getting the data. Inject the Curriculum service into your controllers. Your controllers then simply call functions on the Curriculum service and get the data.

```
angular.module('resources.curriculum', ['..'])
.factory('Curriculum', function ($http, $q) {
  return {
    create: function(dataToSave) {
      var deferred = $q.defer()

      http.get('...').success(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data)
      }).error(function(err) {
        deferred.reject(err)
      })
      return deferred.promise
    }
  }
})
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, Curriculum) {
  $scope.someValue = Curriculum.create($scope.someDataToSave)
})
```

Comment: It seems the $scope dependency is available only for controllers. And I need it in my service... Any idea?

Comment: In you controller you call the Curriculum service and handle the success callback using promises or a callback function. Example using callback function: Curriculum.create($scope.dataToSave, function(dataFromServer) { $scope.data = dataFromServer ))

Comment: I am not sure I am following you here... Can you please provide a more detailled code sample if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to create angularjs service and call particular request on click of some button. This way you call requests in a synchronous way.

Comment: Ummm. What do mean? The idea is not to make requests synchronous but to factor out what is now an anonymous callback into a named callback.